# Automating deployments to Artifactory Distribution Repo

Tags: artifactory, bintray

I'm wondering how to deploy artifacts to [Artifactory's Distribution repo](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Distribution+Repository) . 
Pushing directly to the distribution repo from gradle (using the gradle-maven plugin) results in the following error:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':artifactoryDeploy'.
> java.io.IOException: Failed to deploy file. Status code: 404 Response message: Artifactory returned the following errors: 
  Could not find a local repository named my-distribution-repo to deploy to. Status code: 404
```

Seems I can't push to a repo that's not a local repo. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can push to a local repository and **then** distribute the build to a distribution repository.

For example, with the [JFrog CLI](https://jfrog.com/getcli/) you can distribute in 3-4 steps:

1. [Building](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/CLI/CLI+for+JFrog+Artifactory#CLIforJFrogArtifactory-RunningMavenandGradleBuilds) a Gradle project.
2. [Publishing](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/CLI/CLI+for+JFrog+Artifactory#CLIforJFrogArtifactory-PublishingBuildInformation) the build information.
3. [Promoting](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/CLI/CLI+for+JFrog+Artifactory#CLIforJFrogArtifactory-PromotingaBuild) the build (Optional).
4. [Distributing](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/CLI/CLI+for+JFrog+Artifactory#CLIforJFrogArtifactory-DistributingaBuild) the build.

Comment: Thanks, I'll go the CLI route. kinda miffed that these new distribution repos can't be automated. :/

Comment: All of this can be automated when put in a CI/CD server. Artifactory is well suited for working in teams. For example - 1. Developer pushes a commit in Git 2. The CI server build and publishes the build info. 3. The QA team approves the fix by promoting the build to the release repository. Steps 1-3 are repeated until the product is ready for release. 4. The release-build is distributed to Bintray.

Comment: Yes, but there is no way to push directly to one of these new distribution repos. At least i haven't found a way to do so. If you know how to push directly to a distribution repo (like you can easily to do a local repo) please let me know